# Has scanf a limited bound on the number of bytes that the user can input?

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

I read somewhere that with `scanf()` I can input a maximum of 15 `char`s. Is it right? Is it bounded?

Comment: `read somewhere`...please point us also...

Comment: if it is bounded, its not 15 chars - why dont you test it out..

Comment: Sorry for the lanuage, but as we say, [RTFM](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) first.

Comment: +1 to Sourav. I haven't heard of anything like that, plus it would make no sense. Please give link to the article so that we can see what it talks about.

Comment: I can't test it out because I needed a fast response and I dont have a PC available now

Comment: @rh0x If you need a fast response, don't ask on Stack Overflow. Your emergency is not our problem.

Comment: I found it on an exam solution of Computer Security... I think the professor didn't remember to nest the scanf in a for loop to check bounds, he made a copy/paste mistake. I'll tell him. Thanks to everyone, I didn't know the existance of %Ns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Has `scanf()` a limited bound on the number of bytes that the user can input?*

**NO**.

However, FWIW, we can impose a limit on the length of the input actually to be scanned. For that. we use the maximum field width along with the conversion specifier. A simple example will be

```
char arr[15] = {0};
scanf("%14s", arr);
```

The above format guarantees that whatever be the length of the user input, (i.e., the data present of the input buffer), `scanf()` will only read `14` `char`s, and hence, even in case of *longer* user input, we can prevent the buffer overflow.

Still, it does not impose any limit on the *user input*. User can still input an arbitrary number (*at least, theoretically*) of `char`s, when asked.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

you can enter as many characters until you press a newline i.e enter . And, yes you can limit too by using `"%ns"` here `n` is no of characters to limit